# Installing VNCServer on Google Cloud Computing VM (UBUNTU)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vnc, vnc-server

I'm trying to install VNCServer on my VM box in Google Compute Engine (GCE), but it was not successful.

I have followed the steps given in [this article](https://medium.com/@francesc/linux-gui-on-the-google-cloud-platform-800719ab27c5).

But still unsuccessful. I get the following error:

```
"Time Out Waiting for a response from the host computer"
```

Can someone please let me know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Installing a VNC Server on an Online Server needs a few basic steps as given below. This can be applied for any server type like AWS EC2, GCP Compute Engine, Azure VMs or even a server in a private cloud.

**1) Step 1: Install a VNC Server on a machine**

The installation steps might be different based on the Operating System. So Google and follow any guide that suits your OS. Make sure you set up a proper username and password for the VNC account on the server, after installation.

eg: [CentOS - Guide](https://vitux.com/centos-vnc-server/)

**2) Open 5901 Port from server**

This can be a firewall configuration, network configuration or even a security group configuration. This depends on the server you are using.

**3) Check whether the VNC server is running on the server**

If you have installed `vncserver`, you can simply use the following command to start the server.

```
vncserver
```

And run the following command to see what VNC servers are currently active.

```
vncserver -list
```

**4) Check whether the VNC server is accessible from outside**

Open up a terminal and run the following command. Let us assume your server Public IP is `104.197.91.140`.

```
$ nc 104.197.91.140 5901
// alternatively you can use telnet
$ telnet 104.197.91.140 5901

// the response should like this
RFB 003.008
```

If this is successful, the you can proceed to the next step. If not, it means one of the following.

- Your server does not expose port 5901 and your public IP is not accessible
- You server does not have a proper VNC installed.

**5) Connect using your VNC Client**

This depends on the operating system you are using. So, you can simply google and find out your relevant application.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that ports tcp 5900+n are open for each of the consoles you are starting.

Answer (score 1):

As your RealVNC client is timing out, I would recommend performing the following checks:

1. Make sure your VM has the `vnc-server` network tag in GCE, and that its VPC network has the correct `vnc-server` firewall rule with the former as the target tag.
2. As suggested in the [guide](https://medium.com/@francesc/linux-gui-on-the-google-cloud-platform-800719ab27c5), check that there are no iptables
   rules in the VM that are blocking Xtightvnc's traffic with:
          
   `$ sudo iptables -L`
3. Check in the VM that the server is actually running on port 5901 (since as [George](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31104273/12429357) pointed out the port number is automatically picked from 5901 onwards):
          
   `$ pgrep -a Xtightvnc | grep port`
                  
   (look for `-rfbport 5901`)
4. ...and that it's responding within the VM:
          
   `$ nc localhost 5901`
                  
   (it should return the `RFB 003.008` header)
5. Then, (as suggested by [Keet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31104226/12429357)) perform the same check from the client machine to discard other higher-level issues with the protocol:
          
   `$ nc [your VM's external IP address] 5901`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Google Cloud Firewall rules- allow all]

I have added "All instance in the network" as target and specified port as "allow all". If changing settings like this works, you where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but If your goal is to have a GUI based linux VM, you can try using [this marketplace VM](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/techlatest-public/desktop-linux) which comes with a GUI and remote desktop connectivity.